# Orientation of cells in the boundary of a swept chain

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics

Fix a chain $c$, a homotopy $g^t,\ 0\leq t \leq \tau$ and take $Jc$ the track of $c$ under $g^t$. Arnold's mechanics text (pg 205) says it is easy to verify that $\partial (Jc)=g^\tau c-c-J\partial c.$

How can this formula be derived? I know $\partial Jc$ must be some formal linear combination of the chains $(g^\tau c, \ c,\ J\partial c)$ but what is the rationale for their signs?

Comment: Consider the orientation on the boundary of a rectangle. Say $c$ is the left edge (oriented upward) and $Jc$ is the rectangle.

Comment: I can arrive at the correct form by checking the parity of each component with respect to an extended frame $F=(\mathbf{e}_t,F_c)$ situated in the interior of $Jc$, where $F_c$ is a frame that gives $c$ positive orientation. Then $c$ has $F$-parity of $(-,+)\sim -$, $g^\tau c$ has $F$-parity $(+,+) \sim +$ and $J\delta c$ has $F$-parity $(+,-)\sim -$. Is this a correct way of understanding orientation?

Comment: The issue is with boundary orientation. $\partial( [0,\tau] \times c) = \tau \times c - 0 \times c - [0,\tau] \times \partial c$.